# How to load a video from Parse.com using swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to find a way to load a youtube URL string from parse.com database in my swift application. I have it so when the user clicks on a button that says video it will load the video that is connected to the URL. I can't seem to find out how to make this work though. Any Ideas on how to code this?

In the data base I have the class called Products, than the column name for the video is ProductVideo, and the button in the app is called productVideo.

edit:

// Unwrap the current object object

```
    if let object = currentObject {
        productName.text = object["ProductName"] as? String
        productDescription.text = object["ProductDescription"] as! String productCategory.text = object["ProductCategory"] as? String
        videoStatus.text = object["VideoStatus"] as? String          var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
        ProductImage.image? = initialThumbnail!
        if let thumbnail = object["ProductImage"] as? PFFile {
            ProductImage.file = thumbnail
            ProductImage.loadInBackground() if self.videoStatus.text == "None"{ self.productVideo.hidden = true
                self.videoView.hidden = true
            }
```

edit:

// Unwrap the current object object

```
        if let object = currentObject {
        productName.text = object["ProductName"] as? String
        productDescription.text = object["ProductDescription"] as!                 String productCategory.text = object["ProductCategory"] as? String
        videoStatus.text = object["VideoStatus"] as? String

        let youtubeURL = currentObject["ProductVideo"] as! String
        let url = NSURL(string: youtubeURL)
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
        }

        var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
        ProductImage.image? = initialThumbnail!
        if let thumbnail = object["ProductImage"] as? PFFile {
            ProductImage.file = thumbnail
            ProductImage.loadInBackground()


            if self.videoStatus.text == "None"
            {
                self.productVideo.hidden = true
                self.videoView.hidden = true
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the URL like you say you do, then you can 
`let youtubeURL = parseObjeect["ProductVideo"] as String` 
and then

```
let url = NSURL(string: youtubeURL)
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
```

Note: This will open the Youtube Video in Safari or in YouTube if the user has the App installed.

Comment: i forgot to add something I'm having it go from a tableview to a view controller and I have to unwrap the object to load everything needed I'm editing the the post to show what I have currently. Would i include the code you posted to this?

Comment: Yes, sorry. In my original answer, I wasn't aware that you had a video view already.

Comment: i actually dont have video in yet thats what I'm trying to get working. in my edit i have code that will display the button for video or not depending on if i say their is a video for the product. However when i say their is the button is suppose to display the video when clicked on it but its not doing anything. I can't seem to figure out how to code it to show the video for the product.

Comment: For that you might be interested in a class such as this: https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player

Comment: that close to what I'm looking for but, I think what you first told me is exactly what I'm looking to do. I dont know how to implement that to my code though. I also just want to say thank you for helping me out with this. it's much appreciated. Any idea how to implement what you fist told me to my project?

Comment: Well you would put it anywhere in the code you posted, after you've retrieved the object that contains the Youtube URL. But as I mentioned, this will open it either in Safari or in the Youtube app which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: when i add that code I get an error. I'll put it as an edit.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the line that says let youtubeURl = currentObject and the error says AnyObject is not convertible to String

Comment: I don't know what your key in Parse is that holds the youtube URL but it should be `let youtubeURL = currentObject["urlInParse"] as? String`

Comment: still getting an error. Would it matter if I set the button to be an outlet or an Action?

Comment: and also how does it know that it has to run that code when the button is pressed? the button i have right now set as an outlet called productVideo